# How do I detect canceled asynchronous post

Tags: c#, asynchronous, post

I use the following code to upload a file and form data asynchronous. What do I need to change in order to detect if the transfer has been cancelled or interrupted and then take proper action?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> UploadFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
    }

    var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Temp/"));

    try
    {
        var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

        var paramName = "formInput";
        var formStreamToRead = filesReadToProvider.Contents.First(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == $"\"{formInput}\"");
        var formInput = await formStreamToRead.ReadAsStringAsync();


        foreach (var fileData in streamProvider.FileData)
        {
            var fileName = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
            {
                fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            fileName = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
            if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
            }
            if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
                {
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                }
            File.Move(fileData.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(fileName)));

        }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a CancellationToken to your signature and provide this value to your async methods.

Comment: Hmm, like this?..                 var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
                var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

                // Log exceptions
                await task.ContinueWith(t =>
                 {
                     if (t.IsFaulted)
                     {
                        // Log t.Exception
                    }
                 });

Comment: No, I meant something as described in https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx. However, I see now that while ReadAsMultipartAsync accepts a CancellationToken parameter, ReadAsStringAsync doesn't. So I would provide ReadAsMultipartAsync with the token, and put a try catch. If your connection is lost you will get an IOException or an exception from the 
System.Net namespace. A ContinueWith, like you have done, will swallow your exception and is not necessary if you have an await in a try catch.